# No locale console Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, shell

I just tried installing `Debian Stretch alpha8` today using the netinstaller. So far so good, the installation went through just fine.

I used the advaced graphical installer and did **not** select to install a desktop environment as I would not need it (OS will be used as a hypervisor). So I selected to install an ssh server instead.

After the installation finished and my server rebooted, I am presented with this:

[image]

I expected to get a local console / login on the physical machine at least (when not installing a desktop environment) but there is none.

I can login using ssh just fine but I would like to have a local fallback soloution, is this possible? What do I have to select to get basically a "Debian Server" (like a Ubuntu Server) with a local console? Is it even supposed to look like this?

Comment: Neither does `ALT + CTRL + F1/F2 ....` anything. Neither an installation using LVM nor using the physical disc directly change anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well apparently it turned out that Debian Stretch aplha8 **does not support** a `NVIDIA GTX 970` graphics card ... ... ... **Setting the primary graphics to Intel's internal graphics did the trick**...